# Send json from ajax jquery to a controller that receive a model

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I try every way to send a json from an ajax call and receive it in an Action, (I've tried with a webmethod and have the same issue), the action received a model with the same properties of the json. But the variable person that received the Action always is null.

here is the code:
Model:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
   }
```

Action:

```
   public ActionResult InsertPerson(Person person)
   {

        return View();

   }
```

And finally the view:

```
<input id="btnSend" type="button" value="Send" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var PersonDto = function (name, age) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    };

    var person1 = new PersonDto("Diego", 27);


    $('#btnSend').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("InsertPerson", "JsonTest")',
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            dataType: "text",
            data: "{person:" + JSON.stringify(person1) + "}",

            success: function (data) {

                alert(data);

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr);
                displayJsonError(xhr);
            }
        });

    });

});


</script>
```

All the tutorial that I follow shows this way to do it, I inspect the json in data and it seems to be ok, I try to do the same in a webmethod and It didn't worked, don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simplify and post only the data as json. Note the type, contentType, and data properties in particular.

```
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("InsertPerson", "JsonTest")',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(person1),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr);
            displayJsonError(xhr);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The error was in the contentType and the type. The data worked in both ways. Why it has to be type POST?

Comment: Using POST puts the data in the body of the request instead of in url parameters. Generally, when you are sending data to the server, you should use POST.